# What are the rules on getting personal prescriptions mailed to you in Canada?

Tags: medications, prescription

I'm a non-citizen in Canada. What are the rules on getting personal prescriptions mailed to me from my home country? I have long-term prescriptions which would (I think?) be much more expensive to get here, but are free back home. I have a sympathetic doctor there who'd dispense them to my children to mail to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import 90 days (3 months) drug prescription supply - it sounds like you can do this in multiple times. There is a concise summary of this at 
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140321030753AARucHH but the closest (imperfect) primary source I've found is http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/health-safety/medication :

"The drug must be for your use or for the use of a person who is travelling with you and for whom you are responsible. The drug must be shipped or carried in hospital or pharmacy-dispensed packaging, the original retail packaging, or have the original label attached to it clearly indicating what the health product is and what it contains"

However I also remember finding this from a more direct government source a year ago when I looked for myself.

Comment: The quote you have there is for nonprescription drugs, though. For prescription drugs, it reads like you have to travel with them ("The drug must be for your use or for the use of a person who is travelling with you") and can't have them shipped to you.